# Get notified of RSVPs for my Google Calendar event

Tags: google-calendar

Is there a way to get notified as people RSVP for my Google Calendar events? The only way I know to keep informed is to constantly open up the event itself to see who is coming.  I like how Outlook does where I see notices of accepts or declines in my inbox. Is there anyway to do something similar with Google Calendar/Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

I get responses to my Google Calendar events. Perhaps Gmail is filtering them for you?

[image: screen shot of calendar response]

The message is "from" the invitee, but the sender is `Google Calendar <calendar-notification@google.com>`.

I've not done anything special and there's no setting to turn this on (or off).